# Recovery postgresql database after initdb

Tags: postgresql

I have an important issue with my database and I don't know how to fix it.

I have postgresql 9.6 in CentOS running. After a system reboot, postgrsql-service doesn't start, so following the instructions in the shell, I launched "sudo /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb"

What my surpirse when I started pgsql... and it is a new empty instance, I had a database with a size of 4GB and has dissapear...

However data must be still in the files, because data folder have a size of 4GB, how I can recover this last situation?

Thank you very much,

Regards,

Comment: can you please add your postgresql.conf file.

Comment: `initdb` will not overwrite an existing Postgres cluster. I'm guessing you now have two Postgres clusters.

Comment: Lesson of the day:  Before running a command just because it is in a tutorial make sure you know the context and what the command does.

Comment: Start the PostgreSQL server using the old data folder, where your 4GB database resides.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver, your diagnostic was the right! I could fix it with FrankHeikens solution.